# how do i capture console logs using capybara or selenium webdriver(ruby)?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, logging, capybara

I am logging certain statements into the chrome browser console using console.log() . I am trying to retrieve all these by using capybara loggingPerf. however, i am not able to do so. 
Please note that i am able to retrieve all the warnings given by google chrome (for example, elements with duplicate id )
**here is my spec_helper file..**

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|

        profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
        profile['extensions.password_manager_enabled'] = false
        # nowam 24-Nov-2015: Added 'prefs' hash to next line to turn off automatic request for location
        # caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("chromeOptions" => {"args" => [ "--start-maximized", "--test-type", "--disable-popup-blocking" ], "prefs" => { "profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation" => 1 }})
        # nowam 11-Apr-2017: Added arg to hide infobar and 2 prefs to suppress request to save password
        caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
          "chromeOptions" =>
          {

            "args" => [ "--start-maximized", "--test-type", "--disable-popup-blocking", "--disable-infobars" ],
            "prefs" => { "profile.managed_default_content_settings.geolocation" => 1, "profile.password_manager_enabled" => false, "credentials_enable_service" => false }
          },
          loggingPrefs: {
                browser: 'DEBUG'
              }
        )
      port =scan_port
               p "generated port:"+port.to_s
               @driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :chrome, :desired_capabilities => caps, :http_client => client, :port => port})

            end
```

here is my test

```
it "Verify helper icon with visibility condition and 
radiobuttonrequired asterisk icon" 
do expect(page).to have_xpath('//label[@data-test
id="20191203062406053642842-Label"][contains(@class , "icon-required")]')
  page.execute_script("console.clear();")


  @driver.manage.logs().get("browser")

 page.execute_script("pega.ui.statetracking.debug = true;")
 # The two statements below should log into the console
 DocStateTracker.clear_n_fill_plus(:xpath, "//input[@data-test-id='20191203061946053761398']", "naveen", page.driver.browser)
 page.driver.browser.action.send_keys(:tab).perform
  page.execute_script("pega.ui.statetracking.debug = false;")
   page.execute_script("console.log()")

    logs = @driver.manage.logs().get(:browser)
    puts "logs : " +logs.to_s
page.execute_script("console.clear();")
 expect(page).to have_xpath('//i[@title="helpericon"][contains(@class , "helper-icon")]')
  end
```

Comment: tried the solution, didnt work for me

Comment: I found a solution. i added loggingPrefs: {
                browser: 'DEBUG'
              }After that, i set he w3c flag to false in chromeoptions. this runs the chrome browser in non w3c mode and allows chromdriver to access the logs